# Visual Basic and AES Initialization Vector

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a problem with the AES encryption in Visual basic. This PHP-code does what I want, but the visual basic code I tried to write always fails with an message about an wrong initialization vector.

```
<?php
function decrypt($data) {
$value = "";
$value = base64_decode($data);
$ivlength = 8;
$iv = substr($value,0, $ivlength);
$value = substr($value,$ivlength,strlen($value)-$ivlength);
$key = 'MyKeygoeshere12345678901';  //Muss wegen der verschlüsselung genau 24 zeichen lang sein.
return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9öäüÄÖÜ\ \:]/', '',decryptAES($value,$iv,$key));
}

function decryptAES($content,$iv, $key) {

    // Setzt den Verschlüsselungsalgorithmus
    $cp = mcrypt_module_open('tripledes', '', 'cbc', '');

    // Ermittelt die Anzahl der Bits, welche die Schlüssellänge des Keys festlegen
    $ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($cp);

    // Erstellt den Schlüssel, der für die Verschlüsselung genutzt wird
    $key = substr($key, 0, $ks);

    // Initialisiert die Verschlüsselung
    mcrypt_generic_init($cp, $key, $iv);

    // Entschlüsselt die Daten
    $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($cp, $content);

    // Beendet die Verschlüsselung
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cp);

    // Schließt das Modul
    mcrypt_module_close($cp);

    return trim($decrypted);

}
?>
```

And thats the Visual Basic code:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module AES
    Public initv() As Byte

    Public Function Encrypt(ByVal strData As String) As String
        Try
            Dim rd As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
            Dim strKey As String = "MyKeygoeshere12345678901"
            Dim key() As Byte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strKey)

            rd.Key = key
            rd.GenerateIV()

            Dim iv() As Byte = rd.IV
            initv = rd.IV

            Dim ms As New MemoryStream

            ms.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length)

            Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, rd.CreateEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            Dim data() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strData)

            cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
            cs.FlushFinalBlock()

            Dim encdata() As Byte = ms.ToArray()
            Encrypt = Convert.ToBase64String(encdata)
            cs.Close()
            rd.Clear()
        Catch err As Exception
            Encrypt = err.Message
        End Try
    End Function
    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal data As String) As String
        Dim aes As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim crypted As String = Base64.FromBase64(data)
        Dim strKey As String = "MyKeygoeshere12345678901"
        Dim key() As Byte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strKey)
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        aes.KeySize = 192
        aes.Key = key
        Dim IV As String = crypted.Substring(0, 8)
        Dim ivby() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IV)
        Dim tmp As Integer = 0

            IV = crypted.Substring(0, 16)
            ivby = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IV)



        MsgBox(aes.BlockSize)
        aes.IV = ivby
        Dim src As Byte() = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(crypted.Substring(8, crypted.Length() - 8))
        Using dec As ICryptoTransform = aes.CreateDecryptor()
            Dim dest As Byte() = dec.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length)
            Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(dest)
        End Using
    End Function
 End Module
```

Could you please show me what is wrong with the decryption code above?

Comment: Don't substantially alter your code after asking the question, especially if somebody already answered it. Also, you should not ask people to "correct code". You can ask what is wrong. We are not a community debugger.

Comment: It's cool that you try to perform encryption and decryption at that age. But to learn how to program encryption/decryption you should really try yourself. This means you sometimes get stuck. In that case print as much data in hexadecimal notation and try to spot the differences.

Comment: I'm working at this function for nearly 2 days, all the time I tried it on my own, but now I have no idea what to do, because my variable ivby always has a different length?!

Comment: OK, I'll help you step by step. First of all, when you base 64 decode your data, do you expect a `String` or a `byte[]`?

Comment: I think it should be a byte, because it contains non-printable characters... am I right?

Comment: Yes, so change it from a `String` to a `byte()`, then retrieve the IV - also a byte array - from the result.

Comment: I think you mean byte() and not byte[], don't you?

Comment: Ok, now visual basic is alerting because the substring function is not a member of system.array...

Comment: Yes, so you need to use a function that works on byte(). I guess `Array.Copy` should work. First create a IV of the correct lenght, then copy.

Comment: You can do the same for the "src" of course. Actually, by now I've got `monodevelop` working for Visual Basic... Note that I can see that at one place you use `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` and at the other you use `AESCryptoServiceProvider`. You also mix encodings. Instead of `Default` or `Unicode` it is best to always use UTF8...

Comment: If I encrypt something with the Visual Basic encrypt function and decrypt it with the PHP function, it works well. I'm not able to get the VB Decrypt working...

Comment: What's currently not working on the VB decrypt? Did you take my encoding/decoding hints, and are you using the same cipher (AES or TripleDES) on both sides?

Comment: OK, I have to log off, but you can reach me tomorrow by using @owlstead ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your convenience, using Triple DES (my system does not seem to contain AES, and your PHP code uses triple DES.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module TDES
    Public initv() As Byte

    Public Function Encrypt(ByVal strData As String) As String
        Try
            Dim rd As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
            Dim strKey As String = "MyKeygoeshere12345678901"
            Dim key() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strKey)

            rd.Key = key
            rd.GenerateIV()

            Dim iv() As Byte = rd.IV
            initv = rd.IV

            Dim ms As New MemoryStream

            ms.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length)

            Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, rd.CreateEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            Dim data() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData)

            cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
            cs.FlushFinalBlock()

            Dim encdata() As Byte = ms.ToArray()
            Encrypt = Convert.ToBase64String(encdata)
            cs.Close()
            rd.Clear()
        Catch err As Exception
            Encrypt = err.Message
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal data As String) As String
        Dim aes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim crypted() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(data)
        Dim strKey As String = "MyKeygoeshere12345678901"
        Dim key() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strKey)
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        aes.KeySize = 192
        aes.Key = key
        Dim ivSize As Integer = aes.BlockSize / 8
        Dim IV(ivSize - 1) As Byte
        Array.Copy(crypted, 0, IV, 0, ivSize)
        aes.IV = IV
        Dim src(crypted.Length - ivSize - 1) As Byte
        Array.Copy(crypted, ivSize, src, 0, src.Length)
        Using dec As ICryptoTransform = aes.CreateDecryptor()
            Dim dest As Byte() = dec.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length)
            Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dest)
        End Using
    End Function
End Module
```

Note that you should be able to replace `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` with `AesCryptoServiceProvider`. Also note that this uses base 64 encoded ciphertext, so you should similarly use Base 64 encoding in your PHP code.

Comment: Note that I had to relearn basic to answer this question. I started off writing MSX Basic when I was 11 and haven't programmed it since well, forever :)...

Comment: But I think Triple DES isn't very secure, is it?

Comment: I nearly solved the Problem on my own, could you please have a look at the "new" problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947841/aes-communication-between-php-and-vb-net

Comment: It is not as secure as AES, but it is not as if it would be easy to decrypt. I'm still using TDES at my company, but we are trying to convert everything to AES. Try and move to AES and see what happens. As said, currently your PHP function also uses triple DES, even if it is named AES!

Comment: There are no known practical attacks on Triple DES (except the meet-in-the-middle attack that reduces its strength to 2^112), but Triple DES is much slower than AES, which is why there's no reason to use Triple DES in new applications.

Comment: @ntoskrnl There is, my Mono API does not contain `AesCryptoServiceProvider` so I cannot give any hints :). I think the above code should work if you simply replace the provider with `AesCryptoServiceProvider` though.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, an IV consist of *bytes* not characters, so you should not use string functions on it. Furthermore, the IV is always the same size as the block size of the underlying cipher in CBC mode encryption. As the block size of AES is 16 bytes, not 8, you should replace it with either 16, or in your case with `aes.BlockSize / 8`.

Comment: What String functions are wrong and where do I have to write the 16?? The aes.Blocksize outputted by the MsgBox is 128? Please help me!

Comment: Ah, oh, sorry, I did not expect the output to be in bits, divide the result by 8... I'll amend my answer.

Comment: I get the same error. For some reason the length of ivby is 23. Should I post the new code?
What do I have to use instead of the String functions?